# How to make customized stepSize for each horizontal bar in Chart.js graph

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js

I have implemented a graph with four horizontal `bars`. Last one has nearly 35k records so the `stepSize` *automatically* is 2250. The first bar has only 20 records.

First `bar's` 20 records are not showing any color as the numbers are less at compare to `stepSize` 2250.

This is my code

```
scales: {
    xAxes: [
      {
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          stepSize: 50,

        },
        stacked: true
      }
    ],
    yAxes: [
      {
        ticks: {
          fontSize: 12
        },
        stacked: true
      }
    ]
  },
  
animation: {
onComplete: function() {
  var chartInstance = this.chart;
  var ctx = chartInstance.ctx;
  ctx.textAlign = "left";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";    
    //draw total count
    charData.datasets[0].data.forEach(function(data, index) {
    var total = this.data.datasets[0].data[index];
    var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(0);
    var posX = meta.data[index]._model.x;
    var posY = meta.data[index]._model.y;
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    if(total.toString().length>=5)
    ctx.fillText(total, posX -40, posY + 2);
    else if(total==0)
    ctx.fillText(total, posX -4, posY + 4);
    else
    ctx.fillText(total, posX - 10, posY + 4);

  }, this);
}
```

This is output

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Maybe you should use log scale instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is not related to [`ticks.stepSize`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/radial/linear.html#step-size), this option simply controls how to create the ticks but doesn't change the size of the bars.

You can define the x-axis as a [logarithmic cartesian axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/logarithmic.html) as shown in the runnable code snippet below.

```js
new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
    labels: ['0-12 hr', '12-24 hr', '1-3 day', '3-15 day'],
    datasets: [{
      label: '',
      data: [20, 0, 0, 34343],
      backgroundColor: ["rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)", "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)", "rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)", "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)"],
      borderColor: ["rgb(255, 99, 132)", "rgb(255, 159, 64)", "rgb(255, 205, 86)", "rgb(75, 192, 192)"],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'logarithmic',
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          userCallback: (value, index) => {
            const remain = value / (Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Chart.helpers.log10(value))));
            if (remain == 1 || remain == 2 || remain == 5 || index == 0) {
              return value.toLocaleString();
            }
            return '';
          }
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        }
      }]
    }    
  }  
});
```

```css
canvas {
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="150"></canvas>
```

Comment: Today I got time to work with it. I have 4 bars with count 12, 1, 24 and 30k. The second bar not showing color rather it shows only 1. How can I fix it

Comment: @R15: Can you please post a new question for this issue and provide the code you have. That will allow us to debug it and possibly come up with a viable solution.